# loop over subsets of datatable

Tags: r, data.table

Assume I have a random data table and I want to loop over its subsets.

e.g.

```
DT <- data.table(date = rep(c(1979,1980,1981,1982),3), 
Id = rep(c(1,2,3),each = 4),
x1 = c(10, 40, 80,12,13,19,9,5,22,13,49,110),
x2 = sample(100,12,replace=T),
x3 = sample(100,12,replace=T))
```

I also have the following function:

```
test <- function(x){x[,3:5]/100}
```

Assume I loop over id, apply the function 'test' to the subsets of the datatable and save everything in a list:

```
resultinglist <- vector("list",3)

for (i in 1:3){resultinglist[[i]] <- test(DT[Id == i])}
```

This, so far, is straight forward. Now my question is, with very large datasets, this can take a while. Therefore: Can this code be optimized in any way, maybe so that no copies of the datatable-subsets are made?

In particular, I wonder what happens if I pass `DT[id == i]` to function`test`? Is this the right approach? For example I could also try to loop and just filter at every iteration, then apply some code on the filtered datatable.

Thanks for any hints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go with `split(test(DT), DT$Id)`.

```
> system.time(resultinglist1<- split(test(DT), DT$Id))
   user  system elapsed 
  0.002   0.000   0.002 

> resultinglist <- vector("list",3)
> system.time(for (i in 1:3){resultinglist[[i]] <- test(DT[Id == i])})
   user  system elapsed 
  0.015   0.000   0.016
```

Even with that few data points it takes 1/8th of the time (on my machine).

Comment: interesting, even though `split`is not made for datatable objects specifically is it? Also the filtering might be more complex, but probably split can handle multiple filters as well.

I'd wait a bit for another approach if anyone has an idea, before I accept this. Maybe there is a more datatabe'ish way. Thanks!

Comment: You can see that the split.data.table method exists but is hidden. However, there is a help page.

Comment: @user3032689 datatables have their own `split` function. That being said, for more complex filtering you can do `split(test(DT), DT[, .(Id, Id2)])`

Answer (score 1):

There is a `split.data.table` method:  see `?split.data.table` so try:

```
> split(DT, by=c("Id"), flatten=FALSE)
$`1`
   date Id x1 x2 x3
1: 1979  1 10 26 74
2: 1980  1 40 17  5
3: 1981  1 80 43 51
4: 1982  1 12 35 96

$`2`
   date Id x1 x2 x3
1: 1979  2 13  8 65
2: 1980  2 19 66 69
3: 1981  2  9 69 27
4: 1982  2  5  4 80

$`3`
   date Id  x1  x2 x3
1: 1979  3  22 100 29
2: 1980  3  13  28 83
3: 1981  3  49  53 55
4: 1982  3 110  89  7
```

If you wanted to extract the 3rd to 5th columns it might be:

```
lapply( split(DT, by=c("Id"), flatten=FALSE), subset, select=3:5)
$`1`
   x1 x2 x3
1: 10 26 74
2: 40 17  5
3: 80 43 51
4: 12 35 96

$`2`
   x1 x2 x3
1: 13  8 65
2: 19 66 69
3:  9 69 27
4:  5  4 80

$`3`
    x1  x2 x3
1:  22 100 29
2:  13  28 83
3:  49  53 55
4: 110  89  7
```

See also `?subset.data.table`